# Case sensitive in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, css, selenium, webdriver

I am writing test case in c# using selenium webdriver.

I have got one Id of button which is "ShowReports" and used that Id to click that button. It is working fine.

First I have mentioned that ID name as "showreports" and not able to click that button. After I have mentioned that exact Id  name which is available on the webpage, it is working fine.

Please let me know, Is the selenium webdriver case sensitive while using css, id elements and also let me know, how to avoid that case sensitive?

```
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ShowReports")]
    protected IWebElement ShowReportsButton = null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Selenium is case sensitive.

No, you can't avoid it. Best way to handle this is to copy the names from the html instead of writing them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a case insensitive CSS selector like this and check

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input[id='showreports' i]")] 
private IWebElement CaseInsensitiveShowReportsButton;
```

Comment: I think this better answers the question. Because OP asked how to avoid case sensitivity. Guy's answer doesn't address that.

Comment: @PatMeeker This answer doesn't address the question because it doesn't work. If the id is "ShowReports", "showreports" won't locate the element. If you read the question again you will see the OP already tried it. `CaseInsensitiveShowReportsButton` is just a variable name, it has no meaning.

Comment: @Guy - It's not the variable name that makes it insensitive. It's the "i" just before the closing bracket in this answer. And because it's insensitive, "showreports" will match the id just the same as "ShowReports" or "sHoWrEpOrTs" or any other casing. That's what case-insensitive means. The last line of the OP's question reads "how to avoid that case sensitive" which can be said another way "how to do case insensitive." Your answer does not offer a way to do insensitive, and therefor does not address that part of the question. This answer does, because of the "i" in the selector.

Comment: @Guy It should work, unless the browser being used does not support the case insensitive selector matching. Selenium Webdriver would eventually use the CSS selector to identify the element. I did not follow the part, which mentioned that Selenium is case sensitive